# Remove floating scrollbar Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, scrollbar

I've got this weird floating scrollbar in Windows 10. I can resize the panel but cannot close it. What is this and how do I remove it (so I've got a traditional desktop again)?

[image: Weird desktop with floating scrollbar]

Comment: Have you tried logoff/logon?

Comment: Thanks. Tried that but did not help.

Comment: Aah, found the problem. This is not my computer and the user had (accidentally?) dragged the scrollbar from the bottom to the far right of the screen. By dragging it back to the bottom and then turning off the `Desktop` toolbar the desktop is now back to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click in an unused area of the taskbar.

Make sure that “Lock the taskbar” is unchecked.

Left click and hold in that unused area of the taskbar.

Drag the taskbar to the side of your screen on which you want it.

Release the mouse.

Now right-click, and this time, ensure that “Lock the taskbar” is checked.